# Related to proportionality. Does x ∝ 1/y equal to y ∝ 1/x

Tags: linear-algebra

Does meaning of x ∝ 1/y is equal to y ∝ 1/x ?  if x and y are some variables then does the above question correct. Also x and y are inversely proportional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\propto \frac1y\implies x=k\cdot\frac1y\implies y=k\cdot \frac1x\implies y\propto\frac1x,$$ assuming that $x$ and $y$ are never equal to $0$.

Comment: Got it now. Grateful to you but sorry can't upvote as I am new here.